# How to know that message was deleted?

Tags: telegram-bot

Can I receive *update* where I know that message was deleted? I scrolled through *Message* object and didn't find such field.
Thanks.

Comment: @Maak yeah, you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such possibility right now